# do while 1-4 menu loop continually repeating for non numerical input

Tags: c, loops, do-while

I'm having trouble with this do while menu loop as part of a bigger programming question, it keeps repeating for any non numerical input. How can I prevent this ?
Any help would be great thanks!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main (void)
{
    int option = 0; 
    do
    {
        printf("--- Menu---\n1) Option 1\n2) Option 2\n3) Option 3\n4) Exit\nPlease select an option (1, 2, 3, or 4):");
        if ((scanf("%d", &option) != 1))
        {
            printf(">Invalid option! ");
        }

        switch(option)
        {
            case 1: printf(" 1 \n");
            break ;
            case 2:printf(" 2 \n");
            break ;
            case 3: printf(" 3 \n");
            break ;
            case 4: printf(" The program has terminated\n"); 
            break;
        }
    }while(option != 4);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: please learn to format the code before you post in here. Code without indentation is just hard to read

Comment: Good time now to learn how to use a debugger.

Comment: you can use `default:` in the `switch` block to catch all other values at once and handle them as errors. But what do you expect it should happen if you enter a non-numerical input?

Comment: Do you need to terminate your program? Just use a break after scanf check.

Comment: What do you want to happen when user does not enter 1-4?

Comment: The program should run until option 4 is entered

Answer (score 3):

The reason it keeps repeating is because

```
scanf("%d", &option)
```

will return 0 when you enter a non-numerical input. `scanf` fails but it does
not clean the input buffer, that means that non-numerical input will remain in
the input buffer.

Because you don't exit the loop on error

```
if ((scanf("%d", &option) != 1))
{
    printf(">Invalid option! ");
}
```

`scanf` will once again try to read from `stdin`. But because of the previous failure,
the input buffer will still have the last non-numerical input and `scanf` will fail
again, and so. Hence it keeps repeating.

You have to leave the loop on error:

```
if ((scanf("%d", &option) != 1))
{
    printf(">Invalid option! ");
    break;
}
```

which will end the program. But if you don't want the program to end but print
the menu and wait for user input, then you have to "clean" the input buffer. You
can use this function:

```
void clean_stdin(void)
{
    int c;
    while((c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF);
}
```

and then

```
if ((scanf("%d", &option) != 1))
{
    printf(">Invalid option! ");
    clean_stdin();
    continue; // to skip the rest of the loop
              // and start the loop again
}
```